# Warning: '\\' will be treated literally inside []

Tags: perl

My **Perl** code contains the following lines:

```
use Math::Random::Secure qw /irand/;
use String::Random;

$c = String::Random->new(rand_gen => sub {return irand($_[0]);})->randregex('[\da-f]{32}');
```

And I am experiencing the following **warning** message:

> '\\' will be treated literally inside []

What that means and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I assume the regex pattern `[\da-f]{32}` is understood as `[\\da-f]{32}` instead of `[0-9a-f]{32}`

Comment: @ikegami - Based on https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=86894 *(bug report)* I see you have some experience with this module and similar error. Why this module doesn't accept standard Perl regex pattern?

Comment: Why? Lasziness :) I suspect the author will be open to a patch to support this feature. After all, S::R already supports `\d` outside of character classes. Note that `\d` is defined `[0-9]` there (unlike in Perl, where it matches 580 different characters). Also, that doesn't mean you should use `(?:\d|[a-f])` instead of `[0-9a-f]` because that will probably have a different frequency distribution.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs for String::Random::randregex:

> Please note that the arguments to randregex are not real regular
>   expressions. Only a small subset of regular expression syntax is
>   actually supported .... Currently special characters inside [] are not
>   supported.

So perhaps replace \d with 0-9

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to avoid String::Random entirely. The already-used `irand` returns 32 bit integers, so you could use the following:

```
my $c = unpack 'H*', pack 'L*', map irand, 1..4;
```

As a bonus, I imagine this solution will be faster.

Comment: **Perfect!**. I won't accept this answer because it doesn't answer the question of this post, however your solution solves my problem. Thank you.